# Redirect domain to mobile version in IIS 7

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have looked for the answer to  this, but I am still having trouble figuring out how to do this.

My company host many websites for people. One of our customers has a site  example.com

and wants a mobile version of it. m.example.com

I added the m to as a DNS alias

I also added some JS to the main index file.

```
<if (screen.width <=800) {window.location ="http://example.com/mobile_site/index.html";}
```

That successfully brings up the mobile version of the site.

But I would like the site to be m.example.com

(Note: I originally had the JS point to m.example.com which just led to the IIS page)

So this is where I am a bit lost. In the IIS panel I see an option for URL Rewrite.

I created a rewrite map called mobile rewrite

with original value = example.com/mobile_site/index.html
new value = m.example.com

Then I set a rule with rewrite map that pointed to this.

That didn't work, so I am here, as I'm not sure what else to do, or if I did it wrong.

Here is the output from the web.config file

```
<rewrite>
<rewriteMaps>
<rewriteMap name="mobile rewrite">
<add key="example.com\mobile_site\index.html" value="m.example.com"/>
</rewriteMap>
</rewriteMaps>
<rules>
<rule name="Rewrite rule1 for mobile rewrite">
<match url=".*"/>
<conditions>
<add input="{mobile rewrite:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)"/>
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false"/>
</rule>
```

Thanks

Comment: Anyone able to assist with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, had to create a separate site that pointed to the folder in iis. No redirect scripts needed. Just that Javascript code